# Как правильно работать с классами, не имеющимися в Android SDK?

Tags: java, android

Например мне нужно выдвинуть строку состояния (статусбар). Для этого есть метод `expand` в классе `StatusBarManager`. Как мне его вызвать? Я примерно понимаю так:

В корне проекта создать папку `android`, в ней папку `app` и в ней создать класс `StatusBarManager` с методом `expand` без тела.

```
package android.app.StatusBarManager;

public class StatusBarManager {

public void expand() {}

}
```

Затем в активности

```
StatusBarManager sbm = (StatusBarManager) getSystemService("statusbar");
sbm.expand();
```

Получится ли так добиться выдвигания статусбара? По идее скомпилируется класс и выполнится точь-в-точь как класс из фреймворка. Если так ничего не получится, то тогда каким образом выполняется обычный скомпилированный код, который поставляется в SDK? Что там находится? Почему выполняется код из фреймворка, а не из SDK?

Comment: В активити `StatusBarManager` из какого пакета?

Comment: `android.app`, но моего проекта. Что будет если скомпилировать? Сейчас возможности нет, очень интересно. Ведь этот же пакет есть и во фреймворке и в моём пакете

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Для этого есть метод `expand` в классе `StatusBarManager`. Как мне его вызвать?

С помощью рефлексии, [например](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15582509/7129209).

Вариант, предложенный Вами, упадет во время выполнения с `ClassCastException`.

Вы определяете класс `StatusBarManager`, далее Вы используете этот класс в классе активити (явно указывая, что этот класс необходимо импортировать из Вашего пакета).

Метод `getSystemService("statusbar")` возвращает объект класса `StatusBarManager`, и это не тот класс, который определили Вы, а системный.

Далее Вы пытаетесь явно преобразовать объект класса `StatusBarManager` (системный) к классу `StatusBarManager`, созданному Вами. Так как это преобразование невозможно, то будет сгенерировано исключение `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Вот теперь все ясно. А как же тогда реализовано в приложении DropDownStatusBar? Я его декомпилировал и там напрямую указан импорт системного класса и вызов метода. Одна активность. Как они его указали, он же не входит в SDK?

Comment: @СергейГрушин, Сложно сказать не видя всего кода.